# Spark doesnt print outputs on the console within the map function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have  a simple Spark application running on cluster mode.

```
val funcGSSNFilterHeader = (x: String) => {
    println(!x.contains("servedMSISDN")   
    !x.contains("servedMSISDN")
}

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(batchIntervalSeconds))
val ggsnFileLines = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat]("C:\\Users\\Mbazarganigilani\\Documents\\RA\\GGSN\\Files1", filterF, false)
val ggsnArrays = ggsnFileLines
    .map(x => x._2.toString()).filter(x => funcGSSNFilterHeader(x))

ggsnArrays.foreachRDD(s => {println(x.toString()})
```

I need to print !x.contains("servedMSISDN") inside the map function for debugging purposes, but this doesn't print on the console

Comment: running in local mode is great for such debugging. what happened when you print something else e.g. "hello" inside the map function, and outside the map function?

Comment: I wanna print them on the cluster mode..

Comment: did you manage to print inside map function when you are in "local mode"?

Comment: when you are in cluster mode, the print to console will be done in the nodes, so you won't see it in the console of the driver

Comment: how to then print them on the driver console in the cluster mode...

Comment: Why do you see the logs on driver console? You can just login to the node's console and check the logs. Another choice is that you can use a log collector to collect all logs from all of your nodes. If you do wanna get the logs at driver node, you can map rdd to a rdd[string] and collect them on a driver node. but I don't recommend that.

Answer (score 11):

Your code contains driver (main/master) and executors (which runs on the nodes in cluster mode).

Functions which runs inside a "map" runs on the executors

i.e. when you are in cluster mode, execution print inside map function will result in print to the nodes console (which you won't see).

In order to debug a program, you can:

1. Run the code in "local" mode, and the prints in the "map function" will be printed the console of your "master/main node" as the executors are running on the same machine
2. Replace "print to console" with save to file / save to elastic / etc

---

Note that in addition to the **local** vs **cluster** mode - **It seems like you have a typo in your code:**

```
ggsnArrays.foreachRDD(s => {println(x.toString()})
```

Should be:

```
ggsnArrays.foreachRDD(s => {println(x.toString)})
```

Answer (score 1):

Yaron already explained to you, that you cannot see the output of a print-statement since it is not executed in your driver but on the worker-nodes.

In addition to his answer note that you can access the *SparkUI* or *Spark History Server*.
There you can visually see which executors are running on which node in the *Executors* Tab. As you can see on the screenshot you'll have access to the `stdout` and `stderr` (if your cluster is correctly configured) and see what is written there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:
Your logs are on worker nodes, so you must check worker logs for these log messages. As suggested before, you can run your application in local mode to check logs on your machine. By the way, it's better to use i.e. SLF4j than just println, but I assume it's only for learning :)

In snippet there is no `ssc.start()` and `ssc.awaitTermination()`. Did you run these commands? If not, foreachRDD will not be executed any time. If the example is ok, please add these line at the end of script and try again, but please check worker nodes logs :)

Answer (score 0):

I use pyspark in Databricks, and this is how I find print messages in log.

Sample code:

```
data = [('James','Smith','M',30),('Anna','Rose','F',41),
('Robert','Williams','M',62), 
]

columns = ["firstname","lastname","gender","salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = columns)

def test_map(x):
  print("1111111111111")
  return (x[0]+","+x[1],x[2],x[3]*2)

rdd=df.rdd.map(lambda x: test_map(x))  
df2=rdd.toDF(["name","gender","new_salary"])
df2.show()
```

You can find print() messages through `compute->Spark worker 0->stderr`
[image]
[image]